# Get n entities that either have no or least recent related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am composing a method that returns `batchSize` dtos. I want to first fill up the batch with `FilterList`s that have an empty set of related `Snapshot`s. If there is still room in the batch, I want to then include `FilterList`s whose most recent `Snapshot` (by `CreatedDateUtc`) is the least recent.

The logic below works correctly, but I would like to combine `GetNeverCapturedLists()` and `GetLeastRecentlyCapturedLists()` into a single EF LINQ query. This would avoid an extra round-trip to the database.

Is there a way to do that?

```
public class FilterList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Snapshot> Snapshots { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Snapshot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateUtc { get; set; }
    public int FilterListId { get; set; }
    public FilterList FilterList { get; set; }
    ...
}

//TODO: combine queries into single query
private async Task<IEnumerable<FilterListViewUrlDto>> GetNextListsToCapture(int batchSize)
{
    var neverCapturedLists = await GetNeverCapturedLists(batchSize);
    if (neverCapturedLists.Count >= batchSize)
        return neverCapturedLists;
    var leastRecentlyCapturedLists = await GetLeastRecentlyCapturedLists(batchSize - neverCapturedLists.Count);
    return neverCapturedLists.Concat(leastRecentlyCapturedLists);
}

private async Task<List<FilterListViewUrlDto>> GetNeverCapturedLists(int batchSize)
{
    return await dbContext.FilterLists
                            .Where(x => x.Snapshots.Count == 0)
                            .Take(batchSize)
                            .ProjectTo<FilterListViewUrlDto>()
                            .ToListAsync();
}

private async Task<List<FilterListViewUrlDto>> GetLeastRecentlyCapturedLists(int batchSize)
{
    return await dbContext.Snapshots
                            .GroupBy(x => x.FilterList)
                            .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedDateUtc).First())
                            .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDateUtc)
                            .Select(x => x.FilterList)
                            .Take(batchSize)
                            .ProjectTo<FilterListViewUrlDto>()
                            .ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like that:

```
var res = await dbContext
    .FilterLists
    .OrderBy(q => q.Snapshots.Any())
    .ThenBy(q => q.Snapshots
        .Select(w => w.CreatedDateUtc)
        .OrderByDescending(e => e).FirstOrDefault())
    .Take(batchSize)
    .ProjectTo<FilterListViewUrlDto>()
    .ToListAsync();
```